# Gradle - Java Project - Generic For Loop

Tags: java, generics, gradle

I have a very simple generic for loop that is causing problems when I attempt to build the project using gradle:

```
for(TaskAttribute taskAttribute:task.getAttributes())
{
...
}
```

Task.java

```
protected final Set<TaskAttribute> attributes = new HashSet<TaskAttribute>();

public Set<TaskAttribute> getAttributes(){return(attributes);}
```

The error I am getting is that the for loop is getting Object, but requries TaskAttribute.  I have my sourceCompatibility set to 1.6.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: how is `getAttributes()` defined?

Comment: Can you show the `getAttributes()` method

Comment: Maybe there's some clash with gradle's `org.gradle.api.Task` class? `org.gradle.api.*` is probably imported by default (just a guess here).

Answer (score 2):

In groovy you can do for loops one of two ways.

```
task forLoopTest {
    // print numbers 8 to 19 inclusive
    for (x in 8..19) {
    println 'this is run '+x
    }

    // print numbers 0 to 4 
    println 'now some groovy'
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
        println i
    }
}
```

Run on CLI:

```sh
$ gradle forLoopTest
```

This should out put.

```
this is run 8
this is run 9
this is run 10
this is run 11
this is run 12
this is run 13
this is run 14
this is run 15
this is run 16
this is run 17
this is run 18
this is run 19
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic set up for the enhanced for loop is :

```
for(<Object_Type> <Object_Name> : <Collection_Name>)
```

I am not sure what `task.getAttributes()` returns or what `task` is, but if you have a   Collection( a Set) called `attributes` you should just change your loop to this:

```
for(TaskAttribute taskAttribute : attributes)
{
...
}
```

Note: Since this is a `private` Set you may be trying to use this from another class, so `getAttributes()` might be returning a reference to the `Set` object. In which case my answer may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Make sure you clean the project and rerun.

Comment: That is what I thought, but I'm still getting this: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
/home/walterjwhite/projects/software/Java/active/task/api/comparator/src/main/java/com/walterjwhite/task/api/comparator/PriorityTaskAttributeComparator.java:39: error: incompatible types
  for(TaskAttribute taskAttribute:task.getAttributes())
                                                    ^
  required: TaskAttribute
  found:    Object
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is that the type of `task` is a raw type, of a class that is generic (i.e. it can be parameterized but you didn't parameterize it). If this is the case, I know that logically it shouldn't make a difference on the result of the `getAttributes()` method; but using raw types "turns off" generics and so it says `getAttributes()` returns just `Set`, without its parameter, which causes things you get out of it to be `Object`.